# 'Act Naturally', is it an oxymoron?

Tags: word-choice

To act is to put up a facade, yet when put together with natural, it contradicts each other. Yet this phrase is used frequently.

"Now, Tom, remember to act natural in front of the examiner and do not be nervous!"

Comment: Some people agree: http://www.oxymoronlist.com/act-naturally/

Comment: Loaded question. False premise. First of all, *act* does not mean "to put up a façade". *Act* means a whole number of things, of which "to put up a façade" is but one. Second of all, "contradicts each other" does not mean it's wrong or ungrammatical or should not be used. You contradict yourself fifty times a day, every day. Everyone does.

Comment: As Kenneth Burke might say:  "Things move; people act."  Put differently, a garbage bag full of garbage thrown off the top of the Empire State Building falls at 32 feet per second per second, and that is one thing.  A distraught man jumping off the same building also falls at 32 feet per second per second; , however, that's completely different!  Why?  Because things just move; people act and have attitudes, intentions, and motives preceding their actions.  Big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/act), one meaning of the verb "act" is "behave". "Behave naturally" doesn't seem quite so contradictory.